# MessageBox em uma posição aleatória

Tags: c#, c, .net, vba

Estou criando um programinha, através do Windows forms. E gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que a MessageBox apareça em locais aleatórios da tela

tipo: uma no centro, outra no canto direito, esquerdo, etc

Comment: Pode fazer um [Random](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0) de 1 a 9 antes de exibir a `MessageBox` por exemplo. Se retornar 1: canto superior esquerdo, 2: centro superior, 3: canto superior direito, 4: canto centro esquerdo, 5: centro e assim por diante.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tudo bem? Estive dando uma pesquisada no seu problema e encontrei a seguinte solução (um tanto complexa):

```
Option Explicit

'Aqui são os imports:

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
     ByVal lpfn As Long, _
     ByVal hmod As Long, _
     ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
     ByVal x As Long, _
     ByVal y As Long, _
     ByVal cx As Long, _
     ByVal cy As Long, _
     ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

' Lidando com o procedimento de Hook

Private hHook As Long

Private msgbox_x As Long
Private msgbox_y As Long

' Tipo de Hook
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5

' Flags do SetWindowsPos
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4

Sub TestMsgBox()

Dim linhaX As Long
Dim linhaY As Long

Dim numeroRandomX As Long
Dim numeroRandomY As Long

numeroRandomX = Int(2 + Rnd * (900 - 100 + 1))
numeroRandomY = Int(2 + Rnd * (900 - 100 + 1))

MsgBoxPos "Nosso exemplo de MsgBox", _
          vbOKOnly, _
          "Titulo da msgBox", _
          numeroRandomX, numeroRandomY

End Sub

Public Sub MsgBoxPos(strPromt As String, _
          vbButtons As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
          strTitle As String, _
          xPos As Long, _
          yPos As Long)

' Guardar Posição
msgbox_x = xPos
msgbox_y = yPos

' Setando Hook
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                          AddressOf MsgBoxHookProc, _
                          0, _
                          GetCurrentThreadId)

' Iniciar MsgBox
MsgBox strPromt, vbButtons, strTitle
End Sub


Private Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal lMsg As Long, _
                            ByVal wParam As Long, _
                            ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
    ' Change position
    SetWindowPos wParam, 0, msgbox_x, msgbox_y, _
                 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE + SWP_NOZORDER

    ' Lança o Hook
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
End If

MsgBoxHookProc = False

End Function
```

Sobre essas variáveis:

```
numeroRandomX = Int(2 + Rnd * (900 - 100 + 1))
numeroRandomY = Int(2 + Rnd * (900 - 100 + 1))
```

Leve em consideração que elas geram a posição aleatória na tela, o número 900 é o máximo e o 100 é o mínimo que eu configurei para essas variáveis, mas você pode mexer a vontade, aumentar e diminuir, não sei qual são os valores máximos, mas 900 não parece ser nem perto do total da tela. Adapte para a sua situação e divirta-se!

**Leve em consideração que** se você acionar essa macro através do terminal, vai ter um resultado um pouco estranho, porém, através de um botão em uma planilha ou em um formulário deve lhe trazer o resultado esperado.

**Edit1:** Havia esquecido de adicionar o efeito de aleatoriedade na MessageBox, mas já está resolvido, apenas gerei os numerosRandom e coloquei eles como eixo X e Y da tela do computador.

Espero ter lhe ajudado!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).